# django don't show form in template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

django dont show my form in my template
where is the problem?

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    massage = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
```

views.py

```
from cheatexam_question.forms import QuestionForm
def newquestion(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', context)
```

template

```
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
      <input class="btn btn-warning form-control" type="submit" value="ثبت سوال">
        </form>
```

Comment: You only construct this for a POST request, for a GET request this will likely raise an error.

Comment: You need an else to show the form when no request is performed. Somehthing like:
`else:
        form = QuestionForm()
`

Answer (score 1):

A GET request is used to *retrieve* the page, whereas a POST request is used to *submit* the form. Here you only construct a form in the POST request. For the GET request, you did not even define a `context`, which will thus raise an error.

```
from cheatexam_question.forms import QuestionForm

def newquestion(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        # …
    else:  # GET request
        form = QuestionForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', context)
```

Answer (score -1):

take the form before request.post like this :

```
def newquestion(request):
    form = QuestionForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
        .
        .
    context = {'form':form}
    retrun render(request , 'template.html' , context)
```

note : context and return is not in 'if' block

Comment: Please *don't*: an empty `QueryDict` can still be a valid POST request: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-request-post-or-none.html

Comment: Wow! Thanks Man You Improve My knowledge. Sorry I'm New Django